# PHP: Calling another class function with namespace?

Tags: php

I'm having a few problems calling a function from a string, as its a lot more complicated than just calling a function, I need to do it inside another class, with another namespace.

I dispatch my routes using this method, I am using TreeRoute package on GitHub.

```
public function dispatch() {
    $uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen(implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, -1)) . '/'));
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    $result = $this->router->dispatch($method, $uri);

    if (!isset($result['error'])) {
        $handler = $result['handler'];
        $params = $result['params'];

        // TODO: Call the handler here, but how?
    } 
    else {
        switch ($result['error']['code']) {
            case 404 :
                echo 'Not found handler here';
                break;
            case 405 :
                echo 'Method not allowed handler here';
                $allowedMethods = $result['allowed'];
                if ($method == 'OPTIONS') {
                    // OPTIONS method handler here
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I register routes like this:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->router = new \TreeRoute\Router();
}

public function setRoutes() {
    $this->router->addRoute('GET', '/test', 'App/Controllers/SomeController/test');
}
```

What I want to do is call function 'test' in class 'SomeController', now 'SomeController has a namespace of 'App\Controllers'.

I looked into calluserfunc but I couldn't work out how to do it with my string format and with a namespace, can someone help me out?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Answer (score 0):

You can call `call_user_func` with full class path like this:

```
call_user_func('App\Controllers\SomeController::test', $arg1, $arg2)
// or
call_user_func(['App\Controllers\SomeController', 'test'], $arg1, $arg2)
// or better
use App\Controllers\SomeController;
call_user_func([SomeController::class, 'test'], $arg1, $args2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the job

```php
if (!isset($result['error'])) {
    $handler = $result['handler'];
    $params = $result['params'];

    $method = substr( strrchr($handler, '/'), 1 ); // get the method's name from $handler string
    $class = substr($handler, 0, -strlen($method)-1); // get the class name from $handler string
    $class = str_replace('/', '\\', $class); // change slashes for anti-slashes

    // then choose one of those :

        // if your methods are static :
        call_user_func_array([$class, $method], $params);

        // otherwise :
        (new $class)->{$method}(...$params); // needs php 7
}
```